# How to get value of <ion-input> in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want value of following input elements so what I should do?

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" ></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well i know a little bit about ionic 2....so what i suggest you to use ng model for inputs like below

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Username</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

for ionic one its ng-model

for ionic two its [(ngModel)]

Hope this will help you a little bit

**update**

```
https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/forms/
```

see the above link..in this they used this.todo inside logform function....i am clear about this but i dont know what is that export class bla bla.....

```
export class FormsPage {
  todo = {}
  logForm() {
    console.log(this.todo)
  }
}
```

Comment: ok I got the version diff for ng-model but now please tell me how I can use this [(ngModel)]="username"?

Comment: as i said i know little bit......by googling i came to know that we can access in components by using this.username....but i am really sorry i dont know what does this do.